# Android ActionBar backbutton and tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, tabwidget

I want to create an `ActionBar` and a tabbed navigation like the google+ app.

I used this example as a starting point  and now I have a great actionbar:

- http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

I've also included a `ViewPager` and a `TabHost` to have tabs and scrolling left/right Fragments.

What i need is to show the back arrow in version prior to honeycomb. 
If I set `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, the arrow is automatically show in version >= honeycomb.

- How can I do that in version prior to honey?

---

What I also want to have is Tabs like the google+ app.

This is how is my tab bar looks:

*removed dead ImageShack link*

...and this is what i want:

*removed dead ImageShack link*

I can't find any example to style tab bars like that one.

Comment: use you custom view in your action bar

Answer (score 21):

I would recommend you the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) for ActionBar compatibility with Android <3. It is a better implementation that the example offered in the developers page.

Using this package, the back arrow will appear when you add to your activity the following line.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Regarding the Google+ tabs, I have found the widget [ViewFlow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) very useful and looking exactly the same. Moreover, you don't have any backward compatibility issues. Have a look to the CircleFlowIndicator example.

Comment: There is also the ViewPagerIndicator library that you could use for the tabs, provided by the same person as ActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) to achieve the desired look. These libraries also work pre ICS.

As miguel.rodelas suggested, use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) for the home arrow. In onOptionsItemSelected you can catch it by the id android.R.id.home.

Answer (score 3):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

//use your custom xml view here

```
View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_custom_view, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

//your logic for click listner

```
setListenerForActionBarCustomView(actionBarView);
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated, download the ActionBarSherlock  and import it as a library here
https://api.github.com/repos/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/zipball/4.2.0

- Instead of using getActionBar use getSupportActionBar
- Download the support library
- Instead of Activity, extend your class as SherlockActivity
- Same with fragments, use SherlockFragment

Then just copy your code, should work perfectly.