# Android ActionBar deleting

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Is there a way, how to delete actionbar (all his tabs and settings)?

I'm trying something like:

```
  public void setUpActionBar(int selTab) {

    if (thereIsSomeActionBar){
          deleteThatActionBar();
       }

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    ....set up new actionbar

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean "delete the action bar"? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to create actionbar. this method is called onResume(), and somethimes, count of tabs changes, and I want to create new actionbar with that count of tabs. imagine, you start the app, and actionbar with 5 tabs is created. then you go to settings (another activity) and set that you want only 4 tabs, and then, when you go back, there should be actionbar with 4 tabs. but when I do it, it shows actionbar with 9 tabs (5 original and 4 new, correct tabs). so I'm trying to delete that 5 tabs first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8518634/1012284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getActionBar().removeAllTabs()` to remove all the tabs from the `ActionBar`.

You also can call [`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) on your `Activity` to force the re-creation of your options in the `ActionBar`.

Comment: I cant get invalidateOptionsMenu() working, since I am using sherlockListFragmentActivity.. and I try that first

Comment: made it, getSupportActionBar().removeAllTabs(); did the trick, thanks a lot :)